# Can an IGrouping enumeration be bound in XAML? And if so, what would the binding syntax look like?

Tags: linq, xaml, binding

I have a list of `Customer` objects, which I've grouped on Country.

```
var query = 
    from c in ctx.Customers group c by c.Country
    ...
```

`query` is now an enumeration of groups (`IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Customer>>`), where each item of thie enumeration defines a group (`IGrouping<string, Customer>`).

I understand that `IGrouping` is: the key of the group (`Country` in my example) and the items grouped by Country. It's straightforward how to iterate through this data with a foreach statement, but what I need help on is how to bind the grouping in XAML.

I would like to use nested `<ItemsControl>` controls, the outer one to list the Country names and an inner one to iterate through the grouped customers for that country. By problem lies with *binding to an IGrouping group*.

Can it be done and if so, would the binding syntax look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. For instance, if you want to bind a `TreeView` to the result, you can do something like that :

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Can a HierarchicalDataTemplate work containers other than a TreeView? i.e. an ItemsControl or ListBox?

Comment: No, it's only for controls derived from `HeaderedItemsControl`. If you want to use another kind of `ItemsControl`, use a regular `DataTemplate` that contains an `ItemsControl` for group items